# Can I make JSOUP to click a button in android studio?

Tags: jsoup

I've been searching to automatically click the web button after the webview loads the link

[BUTTON IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVHFj.png)

Here if you see the photo above you can see two buttons, If the webview loads the link it will show you that part, but I would like to let the user navigate into another page if you select the "STUDENT" button.

I've been thinking of loading the link of STUDENT button but there are no links found once clicked, Do you have something in mind to make my idea come true?